# Why does this query result in a "missing FROM clause"?

Tags: sql, postgresql

Why below sql statement keeps getting missing FROM clause entry for table error?
How to adjust this?

```
WITH SUBID AS (
    SELECT * FROM "B_COLLECTION"."COLL_C_RECORD"
),
TR AS (
  SELECT * FROM "B_TRACE"."PERSONAL_TC_RECORD"
)
SELECT "SUBJECT_C_ID" 
FROM "B_COLLECTION"."COLL_C_RECORD"
WHERE ( SUBID.SUBJECT_ID = TR.PERSONAL_S_ID ) 
  AND ( TR.STATE_ID ='5' OR TR.STATE_ID  = 'A' OR TR.STATE_ID = 'C');
```

Comment: The main SELECT doesn't include SUBID in the FROM list.

Comment: Did you mean to write `from subid join tr on ...` in the main SELECT statement?

Comment: Unrelated, but: `TR.STATE_ID ='5' OR TR.STATE_ID  = 'A' OR TR.STATE_ID = 'C'` can be simplified to `TR.STATE_ID IN ('5', 'A', 'C')`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are declaring SUBID and TR just fine, but since these are tables, your select statement does not know them yet.

Here you need to enter SUBID and TR in FROM clauses of your query. It should look somewhat like

```
WITH SUBID AS (
        SELECT * FROM "B_COLLECTION"."COLL_C_RECORD"
                  ) ,
        TR AS (
                      SELECT * FROM "B_TRACE"."PERSONAL_TC_RECORD"
                  )
SELECT "SUBJECT_C_ID" FROM SUBID
WHERE SUBID."SUBJECT_ID" IN 
   (SELECT "PERSONAL_S_ID" FROM TR
    WHERE TR."STATE_ID" = '5'
    OR TR."STATE_ID" = 'A'
    OR TR."STATE_ID" = 'C');
```

That is why you use WITH Clause only on repeating queries. Here it would actually be much nicier to use:

```
SELECT "SUBJECT_ID" FROM "B_COLLECTION"."COLL_C_RECORD" SUBID
WHERE SUBID."SUBJECT_ID" IN 
  (SELECT "PERSONAL_S_ID" FROM "B_TRACE"."PERSONAL_TC_RECORD" TR
   WHERE TR."STATE_ID" = '5'
   OR TR."STATE_ID" = 'A'
   OR TR."STATE_ID" = 'C');
```

Comment: Given the use of those dreaded quoted identifiers in the CTEs, it might also need those dreaded quoted identifiers for the column names. E.g. `select "PERSONAL_S_ID" FROM tr` and `WHERE TR."STATE_ID" ...`

Comment: Fine point. I will remove those double quotes from the answer

Comment: No, I meant you need to **add** them.

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name Yes, but you can also remove them and not use any, right? I just tested those queries on SQLFiddle and they work. I am pretty sure that this answer is already right

Comment: No, you can't `"PERSONAL_S_ID"` is a different column name than `PERSONAL_S_ID`

Comment: aaahhhh... that is what you mean. Sorry, i got that now.

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name Isn't double-quote just the standard SQL way to quote names with spaces/special characters or keywords?  I thought a quoted or non-quoted column name would refer to the same column? Or is this different in PostGresql somehow?

Comment: The SQL standard defines a quoted identifier to be case sensitive. So `"FooBar"` is different to `"foobar"` or `"FOOBAR"`. The SQL standard requires all non-quoted identifiers to be folded to uppercase. So according to the standard `"FOOBAR"` and `foobar` are the same but `"foobar"` and `foobar` are not. However, Postgres deviates from that by folding unquoted identifiers to lowercase. So `"FOOBAR"` and `foobar` are not the same in PostgreSQL, but `"foobar"` and `foobar` are. See [the manual](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-syntax-lexical.html#SQL-SYNTAX-IDENTIFIERS) for details.

Comment: Thanks a lot.
What kinda situation I can use with as clause in postegresql if I can't use it here?

Comment: @fink168 You can use it here but it is just longer and harder to read. The WITH clause is properly used when you declare a query that is performed in your query multiple times.